# $f(x)=a_1\sin x+a_2\sin 2x+a_3\sin 3x+...+a_n\sin nx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let be the function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R $ and the real numbers $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$, where $n$ is a positive integer, $n\ge 2$.
$$f(x)=a_1\sin x+a_2\sin 2x+a_3\sin 3x+...+a_n\sin nx$$
Prove that if $$f(x)\ge 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R $$ then $$a_1=a_2= ...=a_n=0$$

My solution:

Let be
$$S(p,q)=\int _{\:0}^{2\pi }\sin \left(px\right)\sin \left(qx\right)dx, \forall \ p,\ q\in \mathbb{Z_+^*} $$

Then I proved easily that:
$$S(p,q)=0, \text{if} \ p\ne q,  \forall \ p,\ q\in \mathbb{Z_+^*}$$
$$S(p,p)=\pi, \forall \ p\in \mathbb{Z_+^*}$$

I integrated the following relationship on $[0,2\pi]$:
$$f(x)\sin kx=0$$
for $k=1,2,...,n$, but I got nothing.

I would be extremely grateful if somebody help me to continue.

**I would like to know if it can be solved without the integral.**

Comment: Are you sure that $S(p,p)=1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing $x$ to $-x$ we see that $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$. Hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.  Now $0=\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin (jx) dx= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k\int_0^{2\pi}  \sin (jx) \sin k(x) dx=a_j\int_0^{2\pi}  \sin ^{2} (jx)dx $ which gives $a_j=0$.